# Why is Firefox overriding my object's allowScriptAccess tag?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I have this object code on my page.

```
<object data='http://example.com/player.swf' height='398' id='player' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='398'>
<param name='flashvars' value='config=http://example.com/config.js'>
<param name='movie' value='http://example.com/player.swf'>
<param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='never'>
</object>
```

If I have `ExternalInterface` calls in my ActionScript code, they will be run on Firefox, but not Chrome. Upon closer inspection using Firebug, I noticed that not only is my `allowScriptAccess` tag overridden, but also a new tag is injected:

```
<param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param name="AllowNetworking" value="all">
```

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Might be that the "never" value for allowScriptAccess is deprecated http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_14.html and Firefox is replacing with a default value (always?). Another reason can be that you might have a js script that is enabling all js to flash communication - adding allowScriptAccess and allowNetworking to all the object tags in the html file (although it should do the same thing on chrome too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out [FlashFirebug](http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug) is responsible for this.

Comment: try to use swfobject instead.